# What's going wrong with this sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `BankMaster` and `#tmp_BankMaster`. The `#tmp_BankMaster` table is inherited from `BankMaster` table. So, data structures are same. Even some data also exist in `#tmp_BankMaster` table is the same as `BankMaster`. Now I want to insert all non-existing data from `#tmp_BankMaster` into `BankMaster`. I have created a query. But, don't know how it gives an error primary key constraint: "Cannot insert duplicate key".

```
INSERT INTO BankMaster 
   SELECT * 
   FROM #tmp_BankMaster 
   WHERE  
       BankID NOT IN (SELECT BankID FROM BankMaster 
                      WHERE BankMaster.BankID = #tmp_BankMaster.BankID 
                        AND BankMaster.CompanyID = #tmp_BankMaster.CompanyID )
```

I am using SQL Server 2005 and primary key is created on the columns `CompanyID` and `BankID`. It is a composite key.

Comment: Your `BankID NOT IN` is _only_ limiting based on `BankID`, not CompanyID. @AftabAhmed has the right idea, not to mention it will most likely run faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't use NOT IN, but you can use NOT EXISTS,You are using composite key you need to make sure those records should be selected from #tmp_BankMaster for which your composite key (BankID and CompanyID doesn't exist in BankMaster). Try this

```
insert into BankMaster
 Select * From #tmp_BankMaster tmp
       where not exists (select 1 from BankMaster 
          master where master.BankID= tmp.BankID
          and master.CompanyID = tmp.CompanyID )
```

or

```
insert into BankMaster 
   SELECT *

    FROM #tmp_BankMaster 

     WHERE NOT EXISTS

     (SELECT *

        FROM #tmp_BankMaster

          WHERE BankMaster.BankID= #tmp_BankMaster.BankID

            AND BankMaster.CompanyID = #tmp_BankMaster.CompanyID 

     )
```

This should also work:

```
  INSERT INTO BankMaster 

   SELECT *

     FROM #tmp_BankMaster

     EXCEPT

      SELECT *

       FROM BankMaster
```

Comment: I can't understand in your last solution. `FROM #tmp_BankMaster EXCEPT SELECT * FROM #tmp_BankMaster`. can you explain me about EXCEPT keyword.

Comment: sorry there was a typo error. except means select only those records from  #tmp_BankMaster which doesn't exist in bankMaster.

Comment: thanks brother i got it. So, i have three choice and i have to select any one from this. So, which one is best for performance?

Comment: you can explore more about UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT

Comment: Which answer is fastest varies by RDBMS and by the distribution of data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the values you are trying to insert into BankMaster. It appears as if you are trying to insert a combination of CompanyID and BankID that already exists in the table.

Comment: in my question i have placed a condition to retrieve only those data which are not exist in BankMaster table. is there any problem in where condition?

Answer (score 0):

n place of inner where put "on"

```
Select * From #tmp_BankMaster t inner join BankMaster s
on t.CompanyID=s.CompanyID and  t.BankID NOT IN (Select BankID From BankMaster )
```

Comment: I think there is a problem in `inner join BankMaster.CompanyID s` it should be `inner join BankMaster s`.

Answer (score 0):

To get the distinct record what you require is something like this

```
INSERT INTO BankMaster 
   SELECT * 
   FROM #tmp_BankMaster 
   WHERE  
       BankID NOT IN (SELECT BankID FROM BankMaster 
                      WHERE BankMaster.BankID = #tmp_BankMaster.BankID )
       AND 
      CompanyId NOT IN ( SELECT BankID FROM BankMaster 
                         WHERE BankMaster.CompanyID = #tmp_BankMaster.CompanyID )
```

But again this has perfomance issue. So consider using Aftab Ahmed.